# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on an Array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So currently I have an Object of arrays, to fill with objects.

What I have currently is something like so:

```
...
let foo = {
   "a" : [],
   "b" : [],
   "c" : []
}
then,

let obj = {
 ...
}

foo["a"].push(obj);
```

this gives me a 
`Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The code you described works fine. I have included a snippet here. This type of non-answer response usually helps a user realize that there is something else wrong with their code. If knowing that this code works doesn't help you find your issue, try to provide a minimal, runnable example that duplicates your error.

```js
let foo = {
   "a" : [],
   "b" : [],
   "c" : []
}

let obj = {
  d: 'hello world',
};

foo["a"].push(obj);

console.log( foo["a"] );
```