# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on an Array of objects (Typeof shows object)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

This was a reposting after clarification from this post: [Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on an Array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699074/cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-on-an-array-of-objects)

But essentially what I have is below

```js
let foo = {
   "a" : [],
   "b" : [],
   "c" : []
}

let fee = {
   {
     'name':'apple'
   },
   { 
     'name':'banana'
   }
}

let fum = {
   'apple':'a',
   'banana':'b'
}


for(let index in fee){
   let current = fee[index];
   foo[fum[current.name]].push(current);
}
```

And this tells me that I cannot push to undefined. 
And when I log the `typeof foo[fum[current.name]]` I get an 'object' not Array as expected.

Comment: You should rather updat/edit your original post. `typeof` will never return "Array", an array is an object. But the error means that `fum[current.name]` returns a property name that doesn't exist in `foo`.

Comment: Your code doesn't run. There is an error with the fee declaration. If you declare fee to be an array like `let fee = [{'name':'apple'}, {'name':'banana'}];` it seems to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`fee` must be an array. Try this

```
let foo = {
   "a" : [],
   "b" : [],
   "c" : []
}

let fee = [
   {
     'name':'apple'
   },
   { 
     'name':'banana'
   }
]

let fum = {
   'apple':'a',
   'banana':'b'
}


for(let index in fee){
   let current = fee[index];
   foo[fum[current.name]].push(current);
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the typo, that code IS actually what I have currently! Still does not work :(

Comment: It works for me! what is the problem for you?

Comment: Oh, I had made a silly mistake in my object key values! (i.e. 'apples' not 'apple') Silly me, I was stuck on this for a while too.. Thanks alot anyways! (:

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `fee` needs to be an array:

```
let fee = [
   {
     'name':'apple'
   },
   { 
     'name':'banana'
   }
];
```

Now your code should work.